# Record GLKView to mov file with CVOpenGLESTextureCache

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

i'm new to opengl and i'm trying to record the GLKView with no luck so far.
here is my code:

```
     EAGLContext * _context = self.glkview.context;

#if COREVIDEO_USE_EAGLCONTEXT_CLASS_IN_API
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, _context, NULL, &_videoTextureCache);
#else
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, (__bridge void *)_context, NULL, &_videoTextureCache);
#endif
    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate %d", err);
        return;
    }


   CFDictionaryRef empty; // empty value for attr value.
CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, // our empty IOSurface properties dictionary
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           0,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  1,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(attrs,
                     kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
                     empty);

// for simplicity, lets just say the image is 640x480
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 640, 480,
                    kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                    attrs,
                    &renderTarget);
// in real life check the error return value of course.


// first create a texture from our renderTarget
// textureCache will be what you previously made with CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate
CVOpenGLESTextureRef renderTexture;
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (
                                              kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              _videoTextureCache,
                                              renderTarget,
                                              NULL, // texture attributes
                                              GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                              GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                              640,
                                              480,
                                              GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                              GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                              0,
                                              &renderTexture);
// check err value

// set the texture up like any other texture
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(renderTexture),
              CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// bind the texture to the framebuffer you're going to render to 
// (boilerplate code to make a framebuffer not shown)

 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);

 glGenTextures(1, &_texureName);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texureName);
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
 glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei) 1024, (GLsizei) 768, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(renderTarget));

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture), 0);
```

this is the method that writes the it the file.

```
- (void)writeVideoFrameAtTime:(CMTime)time {

    if (_videoTextureCache == NULL)
        return;

        BOOL success = [_assetWriterPixelBufferInput appendPixelBuffer:renderTarget withPresentationTime:time];
        //NSLog(@"writing");
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Pixel Buffer not appended");
        }

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to record footage from your view for later playback at a high framerate I may have an alternative method..

Comment: which alternative? i'm trying to create a mp4/mov movie file.

Comment: As opposed to capturing from the glk at runtime, you could recored the input as the game or whatever is playing then restart the simulation play it back in the background as you render to an offscreen framebuffer - then you could assemble the frames into a video. With this method it would be fine to get 1-10 fps as it is in the background.

Comment: mm.. I need to record the screen at runtime and it is not for game play demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it is free and it is very simple to use
https://developers.everyplay.com